# allure-behave not generating testCaseId in allure reports

Tags: python, allure

I've decided to try incorporating allure-docx into my automated behave tests to see if I can generate a docx/pdf export of my allure report.

When I'm trying to generate the docx/pdf I'm seeing a 'KeyError: testCaseId' complaining about the json report files that have been generated by the allure-behave formatter.  When I dig a little deeper it appears to me that allure-behave isn't adding the 'testCaseId' to the allure report json files, which is what I'd expected.

**Behave test run**

```
> python -m behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure_reports
```

**Extract from allure report json file**

```
...
  "start": 1692097370560,
  "stop": 1692097377262,
  "uuid": "8671c7f6-09e0-4e9d-9c57-d28a03dab6be",
  "historyId": "59156b7cd1b11f2072f76e9aabf7cebe",
  "fullName": "Scenario name here",
  "labels": [{"name": "severity", "value": "normal"}],
...
```

**Attempt to export to docx using allure-docx**

```
> allure-docx allure_reports filename.docx

Template: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/bin/allure-docx", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allure_docx/commandline.py", line 87, in main
    report_builder = ReportBuilder(allure_dir=allure_dir, config=report_config)
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allure_docx/report_builder.py", line 56, in __init__
    self._build_data()
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allure_docx/report_builder.py", line 145, in _build_data
    id_sorted_recent_results = sorted(recent_results, key=lambda x: x["testCaseId"])
  File "/Users/damian.lord/Projects/nhsuk.tools/nhsuk.tools.body-mass-index/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allure_docx/report_builder.py", line 145, in <lambda>
    id_sorted_recent_results = sorted(recent_results, key=lambda x: x["testCaseId"])
KeyError: 'testCaseId'
```

Looking at the allure / allure-behave source I'm expecting to see "testCaseId" in between "historyId" and "fullName" in the json files, but it seems to be missing.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue where no 'testCaseId' is added to the report json?  I'm wondering if this is a bug or perhaps I'm missing a simple way to ensure it's added (e.g. do I need to add something like `@TmsLink("test-1")` in the tests?  I'm not applying any specific allure labels/links at the moment in the scenarios.

The allure report itself is fine from a visual perspective, I can run allure serve/generate fine and see the visual report.  I'm just struggling to incorporate `allure-docx`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.